# Optional file with retrofit Android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, multipart

I have a android app when I post 4 params: name, description image 1 and image 2, but image 1 and image 2 are optionals.

With retrofit post ok when I sent all params, but when I sent only name and description and retrofit said "Multipart body must have at least one part."

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You're use the @multipart annotation, which forces you to send at least one part !

you can use two methods instead of that:

first:

`void method (int id, String name, String description){}`

second:

`@multipart
 void method2 (int id, Part image1, Part image2){}`